# I want to to find a way to get my appropriate result in 1 mysql query

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table name `order_history` where I store both `old_status` and `new_status` of company orders.
the schema of table :

```
CREATE TABLE order_history (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  old_status longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  new_status longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  created_at datetime NOT NULL,
  order_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
 }
```

The insert to populate is :

```
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (1, '56', '714', '2020-12-20 21:37:54', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (2, '714', '61', '2020-12-20 21:37:56', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (3, '61', '713', '2020-12-20 21:38:17', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (4, '713', '42', '2020-12-20 21:38:26', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (5, '42', '51', '2020-12-20 21:59:17', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (6, '56', '714', '2020-12-20 22:21:27', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (7, '714', '61', '2020-12-20 22:21:29', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (8, '61', '713', '2020-12-20 22:24:28', 94471496);
INSERT INTO order_history (id, old_status, new_status, created_at, order_id) VALUES (9, '713', '42', '2020-12-20 22:24:43', 94471496);
```

And Now the question I want to find the `TIMEDIFF` of `created_at`s between rows that `new_status=61` and rows that `new_status=42 and old_status=713`.

So in the example the affected rows should be (2,4,7,9) , and the right answer will be the `TIMEDIFF` between rows with ids (2,4) and rows with ids (7,9). But my query returns 3 results instead of 2 and it also calculate the `TIMEDIFF` between rows (2,9).
How can I exclude this result?
Here is my query:

```
select *
from (select oschStart.order_id as order_id, TIMEDIFF(oschEnd.created_at, oschStart.created_at) as confirm_time
      from (select osch1.order_id, osch1.created_at
            from order_history osch1
            where osch1.old_status = 713
              and osch1.new_status = 42
           ) oschEnd
               join (select osch1.order_id, osch1.created_at
                     from order_history osch1
                     where osch1.new_status = 61
      ) oschStart
                    on oschStart.order_id = oschEnd.order_id and oschEnd.created_at > oschStart.created_at) order_time;
```

Comment: Why row 1 - it doesn't have a 61 on new or old status..(row 3 does)

Comment: @P.Salmon yes I edited my question , tnx for mentioning that

Comment: You should explain clearly the rule why (2, 9) should *not* be considered or conversely add an additional rule explaining what should be considered. For example if, there are multiple rows with old_status = 713 and new_status = 42 whose created_at value is greater than the created_at value for a row whose new_status value is 61 and assuming all these rows have the same order_id, then just select the row with the minimum created_at date. But don't let me put words in your mouth.

Comment: @Booboo the (2,9) shouldn't be because we have the row (7) that is another start between them

Comment: @slifer2015 But you haven't explained *why* row 7 should be preferred to row 9.

Comment: @Booboo because of their ids they are 2 groups really

start : with new_status=61 |
end : with new_status=42 and old_status = 713

so we have : 
2 - start
4 - end
//////////////////////
7 - start
9 - end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach is to use a correlated sub query

```
select *,
        timediff(
        (select created_at from order_history oh1 
            where oh1.order_id = oh.order_id and
                  oh1.id > oh.id and
                  oh1.old_status = '713' and oh1.new_status = '42'
         order by oh1.id asc limit 1),oh.created_at) diff
from order_history oh
where  new_status = 61;
```

Comment: Nice one! using limit. Brilliant

Answer (score 2):

**Why you have the unwanted results?**

`oschStart` will result rows[2,7] and `oschEnd` will result rows [4,9]. Joining these subqueries will result in 4 rows [(2,4),(2,9),(7,4),(7,9)]. Your condition (`on oschStart.order_id = oschEnd.order_id and oschEnd.created_at > oschStart.created_at`) will result in these three rows: [(2,4),(2,9),(7,9)]. It wont prune (2,9) because also 9[`created_date`] > 2[`created_date`]. So your query will match a `oschStart` with all `oschEnd`s that occurs after it. But You need it to be matched with the first occurring `oschEnd`

**Solution**

Use `group by`. If you group by your query results on a field and put other fields on your select part, Mysql will fill those fields with first row of that "group". So assuming that `order_history` is sorted on `created_date` you may use this query:

```
select order_time.id , order_time.*
from (
    select oschStart.id as id, oschStart.order_id as order_id, 
    TIMEDIFF(oschEnd.created_at, oschStart.created_at) as confirm_time
      from (select osch1.order_id, osch1.created_at
            from order_history osch1
            where osch1.old_status = 713
              and osch1.new_status = 42
           ) oschEnd
               join (select osch1.id as id, osch1.order_id, osch1.created_at
                     from order_history osch1
                     where osch1.new_status = 61
      ) oschStart
                    
on oschStart.order_id = oschEnd.order_id 
and oschEnd.created_at > oschStart.created_at)
 order_time
 group by order_time.id;
```

Comment: nice nice saeed :))

Comment: Your solution is right but you can not run it because of your first select line, you need to change first line from `select order_time.id , order_time.*` to `select order_time.id, MIN(order_time.confirm_time) as confirm_time , MIN(order_time.order_id) as order_id` or sth like it